# How can I style the command being entered in a bash prompt?

Tags: command-line, bash, terminal, ps1

While watching [this intro video](http://vimeo.com/75702540) to Brunch, at about t=1:30 the command prompt being used has some very cool styles.

The part I'm interested in is how the presenter managed to colour the text being entered on the prompt, **while it's being entered**.  It looks like the first argument is coloured green when it becomes a valid executable command & purple when it's invalid.  Successive arguments appear white, though it looks like a valid file path gets an underline (see ~ t=2:01).

What's the trick here?  Is this a custom terminal emulator?  Is it some kind of magic $PS1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can do this in bash. But it is possible in other shells, e.g. in zsh

https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting ) or in fish 
[http://fishshell.com/ ).](http://fishshell.com/%20%29)

Comment: Looks like fish does it all out of the box.  Thanks!